# TranscoderException when converting svg to image using Batik

Tags: svg, batik

I was trying to convert an svg document to JPG using batik (I tried both 1.8 and 1.7 versions with the same reuslt). Unluckily some svg elements (*clippath*, *fegaussianblur*, *fecomponenttransfer*, *femerge*) cause the following (or similar, depending on the svg tag) trace:

```
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:

The current document is unable to create an element of the requested type (namespace: http://www.w3.org/2000/svg, name: clippath).
at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone point out any solution for this problem?

Thanks,

Laura

UPDATE: Here is my input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- $Id$ -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20000303 Stylable//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/03/WD-SVG-20000303/DTD/svg-20000303-stylable.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400"
height="300"> <defs> <clippath id="shielddx"> <rect
rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="300"
stroke-width="0.000001"></rect> </clippath> <clippath id="shielddy"> <rect
fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="331" height="210"></rect> </clippath> <filter
id="a5a87bf2-0ea3-4664-8ceb-bd50b883a117" height="120%"> <fegaussianblur
in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></fegaussianblur> <fecomponenttransfer>
<fefunca type="linear" slope="0.2"></fefunca></fecomponenttransfer>       <femerge> <femergenode></femergenode>
<femergenode in="SourceGraphic"></femergenode></femerge> </filter></defs>    <rect rx="0" ry="0"
fill="#2D2D2D" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300"
stroke-width="0.000001"></rect> <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="#2D2D2D"
x="59" y="40" width="331" height="210" stroke-width="0.000001"></rect>
<g zIndex="1"></g> <g zIndex="1"> <path fill="none"
d="M 59 198.5 L 390 198.5" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"
stroke-dasharray="8,3" zIndex="1"></path> <path fill="none"
d="M 59 145.5 L 390 145.5" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"
stroke-dasharray="8,3" zIndex="1"></path> <path fill="none"
d="M 59 93.5 L 390 93.5" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"
stroke-dasharray="8,3" zIndex="1"></path> <path fill="none"
d="M 59 40.5 L 390 40.5" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"
stroke-dasharray="8,3" zIndex="1"></path> <path fill="none"
d="M 59 250.5 L 390 250.5" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"
stroke-dasharray="8,3" zIndex="1"></path></g> <g zIndex="2"> <path
fill="none" d="M 224.5 250 L 224.5 256" stroke="#7E7E7E"
stroke-width="1"></path> <path fill="none" d="M 306.5 250 L 306.5 256"
stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"></path> <path fill="none"
d="M 389.5 250 L 389.5 256" stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1"></path> <path
fill="none" d="M 141.5 250 L 141.5 256" stroke="#7E7E7E"
stroke-width="1"></path> <path fill="none" d="M 59 250.5 L 390 250.5"
stroke="#7E7E7E" stroke-width="1" zIndex="7" visibility="visible"></path>  </g>
<g zIndex="2"> <text x="23" y="145"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font- size:11px;color:#7E7E7E;font-weight:normal;fill:#7E7E7E;"
zIndex="7" transform="rotate(270 23 145)" text-anchor="middle"
visibility="visible"> <tspan x="23">Quarter Overview</tspan></text></g> <g
zIndex="3"> <g visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1"
transform="translate(59,40)" clip-path="url(#shielddy)"> <rect
fill="#1E97E3" x="18" y="110.25" width="47" height="31.55000000000001"
stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"></rect> <rect
fill="#1E97E3" x="101" y="36.75" width="47" height="57.75"
stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"></rect> <rect
fill="#1E97E3" x="183" y="68.25" width="47" height="84.05000000000001"
stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"></rect> <rect
fill="#1E97E3" x="266" y="94.5" width="47" height="78.80000000000001"
stroke-width="0.000001" stroke="#FFFFFF" rx="0" ry="0"></rect></g> <g
visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(59,40)"></g></g>    <text
x="200" y="25"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font- size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;top:10;fill:#FFFFFF;"
text-anchor="middle" zIndex="4"> <tspan x="200">Quarterly
Performance</tspan></text> <g zIndex="7" transform="translate(166,273)"> <g
zIndex="1" clip-path="url(#shielddx)"> <g> <g zIndex="1"
transform="translate(8,3)"> <path fill="#1E97E3"
d="M 1 6 L 11 6 11 16 1 16 Z" style="cursor:pointer;" stroke="#1E97E3"
stroke-width="0.000001"></path> <text x="17" y="15"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#A5A5A5;fill:#A5A5A5;"
text-anchor="start" zIndex="2"> <tspan x="17">Series 1</tspan> </text>
</g> </g> </g> </g> <g zIndex="7"> <text x="100.375" y="267"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font- size:11px;width:63px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="100.375">Q1</tspan>  </text>
<text x="183.125" y="267"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:63px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="183.125">Q2</tspan> </text>
<text x="265.875" y="267"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:63px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="265.875">Q3</tspan></text>
<text x="348.625" y="267"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:63px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="middle" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="348.625">Q4</tspan> </text></g>
<g zIndex="7"> <text x="51" y="256.1"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:146px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="end" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="51">-10</tspan></text>
<text x="51" y="203.6"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:11px;width:146px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="end" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="51">0</tspan></text>
<text x="51" y="151.1"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-  size:11px;width:146px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="end" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="51">10</tspan></text>
<text x="51" y="98.6"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font- size:11px;width:146px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="end" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="51">20</tspan></text>
<text x="51" y="46.1"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font- size:11px;width:146px;color:#7E7E7E;line-height:14px;fill:#7E7E7E;"
text-anchor="end" visibility="visible"> <tspan x="51">30</tspan></text></g>
<text x="64" y="60"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;color:#999999;fill:#999999;"
text-anchor="start" zIndex="8"> <tspan x="64">Demo</tspan></text> <text
x="385" y="60"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;color:#999999;fill:#999999;"
text-anchor="end" zIndex="8"> <tspan x="385">Demo</tspan></text> <text
x="64" y="245"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;color:#999999;fill:#999999;"
text-anchor="start" zIndex="8"> <tspan x="64">Demo</tspan></text> <text
x="385" y="245"
style="font-family:Segoe UI, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;color:#999999;fill:#999999;"
text-anchor="end" zIndex="8"> <tspan x="385">Demo</tspan></text> <g
zIndex="9"> <g visibility="visible" zIndex="1"
transform="translate(59,40)" clip-path="url(#shielddy)"> <rect
fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="18" y="110.25" width="47"
height="31.55000000000001" isTracker="1463661560361"
fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible" style=""></rect> <rect
fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="101" y="36.75" width="47" height="57.75"
isTracker="1463661560361" fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible"
style=""></rect> <rect fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="183" y="68.25"
width="47" height="84.05000000000001" isTracker="1463661560361"
fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible" style=""></rect> <rect
fill="rgb(192,192,192)" x="266" y="94.5" width="47"
height="78.80000000000001" isTracker="1463661560361"
fill-opacity="0.0001" visibility="visible" style=""></rect> </g> </g> </svg>
```

Comment: Hi, here is my input file:

Comment: SVG is case sensitive, your input file is invalid

Comment: Yes, I fixed it but conversion fails as well (see following comments). 
Just to point out that this svg was the offline version of a web page (built using apache wicket).

Comment: If some tool is creating that file, raise a bug on that tool's bugtracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG is a case sensitive language. clippath is invalid, the correct name is clipPath.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I fixed all "erroneous" components with the correct case. Now I get this error org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
Enclosed Exception:
null
 at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's a different problem and a different question. You should create a new question with your new input file.

Comment: UPDATE: conversion to png works fine. Maybe previous error was due to missing dependencies or to broken JPEGTranscoder.